# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly - XAMPP(No much info on Log)

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am trying to start mySQL on my XAMPP. It was run yesterday perfectly. But suddenly it is not working.

```
01:22:37  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
01:22:38  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
01:22:39  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
01:22:39  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
01:22:39  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
01:22:39  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
01:22:39  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
01:22:39  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
01:22:39  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
01:22:39  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

In log file

```
2022-11-25  1:22:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-11-25  1:22:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-11-25  1:22:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-11-25  1:22:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-11-25  1:22:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-11-25  1:22:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-11-25  1:22:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-11-25  1:22:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-11-25  1:22:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-11-25  1:22:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'G:\Xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-11-25  1:22:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'G:\Xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-11-25  1:22:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-11-25  1:22:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.25 started; log sequence number 3580223; transaction id 4597
2022-11-25  1:22:38 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from G:\Xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-11-25  1:22:38 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-11-25  1:22:38 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-11-25  1:31:54 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Database page corruption on disk or a failed file read of tablespace mysql/transaction_registry page [page i2022-11-25  1:31:57 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: Aria engine: starting recovery
recovered pages: 0% 100% (0.0 seconds); tables to flush: 1 0
 (0.0 seconds);
```

Any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it worked after restoring backups of the xampp MySQL databases.

Follow the steps to recover.
Stop the server, both apache and MySQL

1. Install brand new Xampp Installation
2. Copy your ibdata1(xampp/mysql/data) to the new installation
3. Copy all the folders in the xampp/mysql/data to new installation

**DO NOT COPY mysql, performance_schema, phpmyadmin folders**

Now start the server and check on phpMyAdmin.